# "structure of query does not match function result type" when returning table from supbase

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I am completely new to supabase and postgresql. I wanted to get top 3 sneaker baught from `sales_items` database.

So i wrote this function

```
SELECT sneaker_product, SUM(quantity) as total_sales
   FROM store_sales_items
   WHERE is_sneaker is not null
   GROUP by sneaker_product
   ORDER BY total_sales DESC
   LIMIT 3;
```

that will return

| sneaker_product | total_sales |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "10" |
| 3 | "6" |
| 4 | "5" |

then i try to create function so i can use easily on react app. here it is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION top_three()
RETURNS TABLE (sneaker_product INT, total_sales INT) AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT sneaker_products.id, SUM(quantity) as total_sales
   FROM store_sales_items
   JOIN sneaker_products on store_sales_items.sneaker_product = sneaker_products.id
   WHERE is_sneaker is not null
   GROUP BY sneaker_products.id
   ORDER BY total_sales DESC
   LIMIT 3;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

after lots of error solving I came up this but still `Failed to run sql query: structure of query does not match function result type`

all i am doing this on supabase web app sql editor.

One more thing sneaker*product has relation with sneaker*_products db as well is that causing problem.Idk but can some one help me. Thanks

tried exact matching types of col but no luck. tried to set sneaker*product type as sneaker*_proudcts db i thought might work but thought thats not the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The aggregate function `sum` returns `bigint`, not `integer`. Either change the function result type or cast the sum to `integer`.

Comment: Ok I tried but no luck

Comment: Then you tried wrongly, or `sneaker_products.id` is not `integer`.

Comment: You can do `RETURNS TABLE (sneaker_product sneaker_product.id%TYPE, total_sales bigint)` to let PostgreSQL infer the type of the `sneaker_products.id` column

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `sum()`'s return type varies depending on the type of its arguments. In my case, where the arg type was `bigint`, the return type was `numeric`.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-aggregate.html